# Ubuntu Port Scan , Security concerns

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables

Scan results of my ubuntu 14.04

```
$ nmap  127.0.0.1

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-05-02 08:43 IST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.0021s latency).
Not shown: 994 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
25/tcp   open  smtp
80/tcp   open  http
139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds
631/tcp  open  ipp
3306/tcp open  mysql

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.29 seconds
```

Why is port open ? I am running LAMP. Are the other open ports normal?

```
$ sudo netstat -tunlp | grep :25
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1281/master     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1281/master

$ sudo netstat -tunlp | grep :3306 tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:3306 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 1101/mysqld
$ sudo netstat -tunlp | grep :25 tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:25 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 1233/master
tcp6 0 0 ::1:25 :::* LISTEN 1233/master
$ sudo netstat -tunlp | grep :80 tcp6 0 0 :::80 :::* LISTEN 1315/apache2
$ sudo netstat -tunlp | grep :631 tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:631 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 2559/cupsd
tcp6 0 0 ::1:631 :::* LISTEN 2559/cupsd
udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:631 0.0.0.0:* 1088/cups-browsed 
$ sudo netstat -tunlp | grep :139 tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:139 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 592/smbd
tcp6 0 0 :::139 :::* LISTEN 592/smbd
$ sudo netstat -tunlp | grep :445 tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:445 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 592/smbd
tcp6 0 0 :::445 :::* LISTEN 592/smbd
```

Using GUFW I have blocked Port 80 incoming and Port 25 incoming 
and out going. What other ports should I block?

How to really seriously lock down Ubuntu? A guide, please.

May I ask email session hijacking queries here?

Comment: iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3306 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED or try 

sudo ufw deny 3306/tcp

kill the process by sudo kill  -9 1281

Comment: Ran sudo kill -9 1281 Next sudo netstat -tunlp | grep :25
results in nothing blank ? I have blocked all open ports shown by nmap in GUFW including 3306 only allowing port 80 outgoing, should I do sudo ufw deny 3360/tcp ,did it anyway.

Comment: yes to kill the 1281/master check the sockets by typing netstat -npl

Comment: checked the sockets , there is no 1281, though may show once I restart my machine ? what may be wrong ? you feel 1281 is malware/rootkit ?

Comment: tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                                       3306 shows in sockets                                                                        May I use GUFW  or should i use iptables ? I am new to iptables...

Comment: i forget to add something in iptables rules 
 
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3306 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j DROP

Comment: The port number is 3306 should to filter or block via iptables

Comment: I have blocked filtered via GUFW , is that enough or should I add the iptables rule ?

Comment: For more security add 2 rules iptables rule plus ufw rule configure logging to watch it

Comment: I have installed LAMP does that open up Port 3306 ?

Comment: Im not sure locate /etc/services this will explain to you all ports number fonctions , sudo gedit /etc/services

Comment: Yes it is the mysql port, anyway blocked all open ports , as I am running only on localhost.                                                                                                 mysql  3306/tcp
mysql  3306/udp                                                                                                                                               how to check if I am backdoored ? I am feel I am experiencing MITB ,session hijacking my emails, ISP suspect proxying/compromised. rkhunter chkrookit are clean . Ubuntu total lockdown guide much appreciated, should I use another distro ?

Comment: jedi@jedi-OptiPlex-GX520:~$ sudo netstat -tunlp | grep :25
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1233/master     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1233/master                                                                                                                                            after machine restart

Comment: the best security is not being connected to the net in the first place